# Double REPLACE on a single field in a SELECT

Tags: mysql

How can I run a select with two replaces on the same field?

```
SELECT `id`, `name`, `address`, REPLACE( `info`, '|', '-' ) AS `info` 
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/" . $SESSION . "NET_SCAN.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' 
ENCLOSED BY '' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' 
FROM `net_scan`;
```

I want to run a secondary REPLACE on the same field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `REPLACE` within it self.

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(field, 'bad', 'good'), 'better', 'worse')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
replace(REPLACE( `info`, '|', '-' ), 'x', 'y'))
```

Comment: Sorry. Bought of you answered the same thing at the same time. Gave you a +1 though.